# MATLAB hide datacursor box when using datacursor

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB to create a GUI. I have an image on which the datacursormode is enabled. This works fine, every time I click a new point is added. For every point MATLAB displays a box with the coordinates (or whatever other text, I modified it using an update function). But how can I remove this text box, I just want a point to be added, no extra information should be displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`datacursormode on` is used to enable data tip display on a graphic object. In other words that text box you want to hide. What the reason then to use datacursor?

Are you using `UpdateFcn` of data cursor to "add pixel" (you probably mean to change pixels color)? Consider using [ButtonDownFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#ButtonDownFcn) callback function instead.

```
function interactive_image(im)
    fh = figure;
    hImage = imshow(im);
    set(hImage,'ButtonDownFcn',@myfunction)
end

function output_txt = myfunction(obj,eventdata,handles)
    pos = get(gca,'CurrentPoint')
    x = get(obj,'CData');
    x(uint32(pos(1,2)),uint32(pos(1,1))) = 0;
    set(obj,'CData',x)
end
```

**UPDATE**:

According to your comment you better to use [IMPOINT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/impoint.html) function available in Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: besides the box it does what I want: putting points on my image that can be dragged and dropped / deleted. I could use the ButtonDownFcn callback and register the CurrentPoint as you say, but then I would have to write code for the drag and drop/ point delete myself?